# Is this how to typecast?

Tags: java

I have to typecast x to store its variable in y, then output y.
Is this how you do it?

```
class TypeCast{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        double x;
        int y;
        x = 273.459;
        y = (int)x;
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if I sound stupid but I just started Java and I'm bad at it.

Comment: WHy don't you try it?

Comment: The answer to this question is too short to be posted. Ask something more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct! Your way will strip off the values after the decimal point and save only the integer part, since java knows that "y" is an int.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the same way you can do for Non Primitive too.